# Jupiter not using conda env

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

I've created a Conda environment (call it test), and have Jupiter installed in my base env.
Below are the steps I am running :

- `conda create --name test`
- `conda activate test`
- `conda install -c Conda-forge -c defaults [some_package]`
- `Jupyter notebook`
- *In a fresh notebook*
  `import [some_package]`

This yields a `no package named ...` error; this despite the fact that I can verify the package has been installed by running `conda list` in the env.

I think the problem is that running Jupiter notebook after conda activate is not running python from within my new environment, but rather using the 'base' python.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Update, this seems to work if I create the env using `conda create --name test jupyter`

Comment: install `ipykernel` in the env, launch Jupyter with **base** active, then switch kernels in the notebook

Comment: See the duplicate - one need not install jupyter in every environment.